# Кличний відмінок для імені Віка

Tags: відмінювання, власні-назви, кличний-відмінок

У мене є подруга Вікторія. Ми звемо її Вікою. Як правильно утворити кличну форму цього імені і згідно з яким правилом. Мені здається, що це буде Віко, але я не певен.

З іншого боку, хоча [вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F)) знає цей варіант імені, а [словник уліф](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) - ні, може це не український варіант імені? Був би вдячний і за інші запропоновані короткі варіанти з їх кличними формами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Віка* — це іменник **Першої відміни**, [оскільки](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par44) він — жіночого роду і закінчується на `-а` або `-я`.

Іменники Першої відміни у Кличному відмінку [отримують закінчення](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par47A) `-о, -е, -є, -ю` згідно правила:

- `-о` мають іменники твердої групи: *дружино, Ганно, книжко, Михайлівно, перемого, сестро*.
- `-е` мають іменники м’якої та мішаної груп
- `-є` — іменники м’якої групи після голосного та апострофа.
- `-ю` мають деякі пестливі іменники м’якої групи

Отже, Кличний відмінок — **Віко**.

Answer (score 4):

У кличному відмінку "Віко":

З [правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par103):

> § 103. Відмінювання імен
>
> 1. Українські чоловічі та жіночі імена, що в називному відмінку однини закінчуються на -а, -я, відмінюються як відповідні іменники I відміни

І в прикладі є "Ганно" у кличному відмінку.

Щодо інших форм - сам я більшість з них не зустрічав, проте [вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F)) дає багато форм:

> Варіанти імені: Віка, Торі, Ніка, іноді — Віта
> Інші форми: Вікуся, Нікуля, Віточка, Вікулька, Вікочка, Вікуська, Нікочка, Нікуся, Вітуся, Куся, Вітуля

З них усі, що закінчуються на "-а", у кличному відмінку закінчуватимуться на "-о", а ті, що на "-я", закінчуватимуться на "-ю".

Варіант "Торі" не відмінюється.